# loading up to 2^32 int

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

I need to load intergers up to 2^32.

Many resources indicates that `cin` or `scanf` simply wont load numbers this big.

What is the most optimal way to load such big numbers?

Comment: `uint64_t` or `int64_t` can go up higher. Beyond that, you'll need to look up bignum libraries.

Comment: What do you mean, "load?"

Comment: Do you need one integer that can handle 2^32 values? Or you want to load 2^32 bytes into memory?

Comment: An integer cannot hold 2^32 _regardless of what you use to read it_! This is because the first bit indicates _sign_. Perhaps you want `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 1):

Either of `std::cin` and `scanf` should work:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    uint32_t n;

//with iostreams
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout<<"read: "<<n<<'\n';

//with stdio
    scanf("%" SCNu32, &n);
    printf("read: %" PRIu32 "\n", n);

}
```

Either will load an integer that's up to but no including 2^32 (and no less than 0). If you need a larger range, try 64 bit integers (signed or unsigned).

Comment: This will "load" up to 2^32 - 1

Comment: @M.M Maybe I've been using it wrong, but I usually differentiate between "up to" and "up to and including", because "up to but not including" seems like too much of a mouthful to me.